# Project management charting

Tags: diagrams, charts

Are there any packages for project management charting - PERT charts, Gantt charts etc. I have seen flow chart packages, but not the others.
Help will be appreciated.

[image: PERT example]

Comment: Yes, there is at least one package: `pgfgantt`.

Comment: My advice: If this would be your first LaTeX experiment and if you have some deadline or other hobbies :), then I would rather use a more graphical software like MS PowerPoint or MS Visio or something like https://www.draw.io/.

Comment: Thank you. PERT charts would fit my needs better because they show interrelationships between tasks. As a fallback, I can create the charts in another package and insert the images in my LaTeX  documents.